# Eclipse RCP Platform Migration

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

Is there any **utility/tool** that can help in migrating an existing `Eclipse RCP 3.6` platform to `Eclipse RCP 4.2` (Juno) platform. (I mean an RCP application running in 3.6 platform to 4.2).

Kindly point out if there are any existing **guidelines/tips** to carry out the same.

Also if there are any downside to migrating to 4.2 platform.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this might help:
[Migrating from Eclipse 3.x to Eclipse 4 (e4)](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2016/01/08/migrating-from-eclipse-3-x-to-eclipse-4-e4/)

Comment: Link is dead, I guess the content was updated and moved here: http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2016/01/08/migrating-from-eclipse-3-x-to-eclipse-4-e4/

Comment: @Manuel Thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no such tool, but you can find some tips and guidelines also at [Migrating Eclipse 3.x plug-ins and RCP applications to Eclipse 4](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse4MigrationGuide/article.html) tutorial by Lars Vogel.

Answer (score 0):

I did some E3 to E4 migrations for work.

- This is a tool you can use: 
  Eclipse 4 Migration Tooling: https://opcoach.github.io/E34MigrationTooling/.

Some documentation on using the above tool is provided on the tool's website and in the website of this page https://www.eclipsecon.org/france2016/session/truth-about-migrating-eclipse-4 (get the pdf)

These are the most useful articles for migrating:

- https://jaxenter.com/eclipse-migration-tutorial-124527.html
- https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2016/01/08/migrating-from-eclipse-3-x-to-eclipse-4-e4/
- http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4MigrationGuide/article.html

Remember, even if you just use the compatibility layer you could need to change some code, i.e. event management in the handlers.

Bottom line, there are no downsides in migrating to E4. E3 Standalone is not supported anymore, and E4 is a more recent technology, which allow to reduce the boilerplate code. The Eclipse IDE itself runs E3 components, on top of the E4 Compatibility Layer.

My sugggestion: migrate by steps: first use the compat layer. Then, if needed, start moving E4 components using the E4 paradigm.